# getting standard deviation of the values in two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two DataFrames and I would like to find the standard deviation per rc_id for one of the columns i.e. `imapcted_users`column in these two dataframes and create a separate column with the name `std` with their standard deviation value

`df1` :

```
data = {"timestamp":["2022-10-29","2022-10-29","2022-10-29","2022-10-29","2022-10-29","2022-10-29","2022-10-29","2022-10-29","2022-10-29"],
       "rc_id":[296,296,296,296,296,100,100,100,100],
       "impacted_users":[1,87,44,8,5,2,7,11,30]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df1.groupby(["timestamp","rc_id"]).agg({"impacted_users": sum}
                                      ).reset_index()
```

`df1:`

```
    rc_id           timestamp            impacted_users
     296           2022-10-29                  145
     100           2022-10-29                   50
```

`df2` :

```
    data1 = {"rc_id":[296,296,296,100,100,100],
       "impacted_users":[201,202,216,300,301,350]}

   df2 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
   df2
```

`create df2:`

```
rc_id            impacted_users
     296                201
     296                202
     296                216
     100                300
     100                301
     100                350
```

`Expected Output:`

```
 id           timestamp             imapcted_users  std 
 296          2022-10-29 11:00:00      145          27.21   
 100          2022-10-29 11:00:00       50          117.36
```

What I would like to have is `std` and put it as a separate
columns (just as an example what values I am looking for from these columns):

```
std(145, 201, 202,216)
std (50,300,301,350)
```

I am unable to come up with a strategy to get this standard dev. for values from different dataframes. I tried to concat the required values and then get the std by aggregation but I guess there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with aggregate `std`, but because pandas [`Series.std`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.std.html) has default `ddof=1` for expected ouput add parameter `ddof=0`, last append to `df1`:

```
df1 = df1.groupby(["timestamp","rc_id"], as_index=False, sort=False)["impacted_users"].sum()
              
df = (df1.join(pd.concat([df1, df2])
                 .groupby('rc_id')['impacted_users'].std(ddof=0).rename('std'), on='rc_id'))
print (df)
    timestamp  rc_id  impacted_users         std
0  2022-10-29    296             145   27.212130
1  2022-10-29    100              50  117.367745
```